# Amazon App Store equivalent of Google Play Licensing?

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

I have developed a standalone "unlocker"/key-app that unlocks features in a separate free app. I am using the Google Play Licensing library to determine if the user has paid for the app and then issue an "unlock" command to the separately installed free app. I know that Amazon applies its own DRM to every app (i.e. the app checks in with Amazon's App Store to see if it's been purchased on every launch), but is there an equivalent to the Google Play Licensing library that developers can use to perform their own checks?

Comment: have you thought about using In-App Purchasing rather than a second app?

Comment: Hi Offbeatmammal, thanks for the comment, that's a great idea! I'm already using Google's IAP in my "main" app that the unlocker would unlock, but there's no reason not to extend this to also use Amazon's IAP, rather than integrating a license check in the "key"/unlocker app. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, would you like to post your comment as an answer? I ended up going with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably to take advantage of the In-App Purchasing solution offered by the AppStore - https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing.html - this allow you to verify the transaction and keeps the user effort to a minimum (only one download, no residual "unlocker" app etc) It also means you can use things like A:B testing to experiment with different update scenarios to see what drives optimal behavior